# Can we install Visual Web Express 2008 and IIS on Windows XP Media Center?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, mediacenter

Is Microsoft.NET 3.5 (and VWD Express 2008) compatible with Windows XP Media Center SP 2 ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have installed 3.5 with VS.Net 2008 on Windows XP Media Center SP 2 without a prob :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can.

Answer (score 0):

yes. Works fine.

Make sure you use the correct SDK for media center though,

"http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=1D836C29-ABD5-4FDD-90C5-5C5ABAE97DB4&displaylang=en"

is for Media Center on Windows XP

whereas

"http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=A43EA0B7-B85F-4612-AA08-3BF128C5873E&displaylang=en"

is for Vista onwards..